# In bash script Symlink are not getting created even though the commands are executed successfully

Tags: bash, shell, symlink, rpm, post-install

I am new to RPM Package enhancement/development and working on post-install script.

I want to achieve the symbolic links creation on execution of post-install script but stuck on a issue.

The script execution is working fine for symbolic link creation but for Upgrade part when I check the Symbolic links in "$RPM_pckg_home/bin" they not getting created though the commands are executed successfully.

### Here is the sample code;

```
Original_bin_path=/a/b/c
RPM_pckg_home=/d/e/f

if [[ "$1" -eq 1 ]]; then # 1 for install

  cd $RPM_pckg_home/bin

            for cmd in `ls Original_bin_path` ; do

            ln -s $Original_bin_path/${cmd} ${cmd}

            done

 elif [[ "$1" -eq 2 ]]; then # 2 for Upgrade

  cd $RPM_pckg_home/bin

        for cmd in `ls Original_bin_path` ; do

        rm ${cmd}
        ln -s $Original_bin_path/${cmd} ${cmd}

        done
fi
```

---

Could you please suggest where would be the issue.

Comment: You're missing a `$` before `Original_bin_path` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry for the typo but it not the case.

Comment: You can always check your scripts for errors in http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the possible typo, this is how you should write your loop:

```
if [[ "$1" -eq 1 ]]; then # 1 for install    
    for cmd in "$Original_bin_path"/* ; do
        ln -s "${cmd}" "$RPM_pckg_home/bin"
    done
elif [[ "$1" -eq 2 ]]; then # 2 for Upgrade
    for cmd in "$Original_bin_path"/*; do
        rm "${cmd}"
        ln -s "${cmd}" "$RPM_pckg_home/bin"
    done
fi
```

Instead of iterating over the output of `ls`, just iterate over the files that match the glob, and modify your `rm` and `ln` commands to accommodate the change in the value of `$cmd`.